# The if session does'nt work

Tags: session, if-statement

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION ['gebruikersrol'] !='1' AND '4')
{
header('location: ../error2.php');
}
?>
```

Why does he only pick '1'? Can someone help me?

Comment: `AND` does not work that way, you must repeat the equality expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you were asking, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION ['gebruikersrol'] !='1' && $_SESSION ['gebruikersrol'] != '4')
{
header('location: ../error2.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION ['gebruikersrol'] != '1' AND $_SESSION ['gebruikersrol'] != '4')
{
header('location: ../error2.php');
}
?>
```

also if those should be numbers you should remove the single quotes from '1' and '4'